# generator is an ideal of a polynomial ring

Tags: ring-theory

I=$\left \{ p\left ( x \right ) \in R[x] \mid p\left ( x \right ) \text{has constant term 0}\right \}$

$I=\left \langle x \right \rangle$ is an ideal of R[x]

I want to verify this claim but run immediately into a problem when using the second condition of Ideal.

> $\forall a \in R[x] \text{and} \forall x \in I, a\cdot x \in I \text{and}  I\cdot a \in I$

Say if I pick $x^{n} \in p(x)$ and $x^{n} \in \left \langle x \right \rangle$, $x^{2n}$ is not in $\left \langle x \right \rangle=\left \{ x^{0},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,x^{\pm n} \right \}$.

What am I doing wrongly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: **Hint** $\ p(0) = 0 \iff x\mid p(x)\iff p(x) = x q(x)\iff p(x)\in x R[x] = \langle x \rangle$.  You should review your definitions since your question seems to indicate misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

We will show indeed that for a ring $R$
$$ I = \lbrace f \in R[x] \; | \; f \text{ has constant term } 0 \rbrace = \langle x \rangle.$$
First note that if $f$ has constant term $0$ then $f(x) = xg(x)$ for some $g \in R[x]$. But then $f = xg(x) \in \langle x \rangle$ by definition so we have immediately that $I \subseteq \langle x \rangle$. For the other inclusion consider that if $f \in \langle x \rangle$ then $f(x) = xg(x)$ for some polynomial $g \in R[x]$. Write
$$ g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i $$
and note that
$$ f(x) = xg(x) = x\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n xa_ix^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^{i+1}. $$
However, this allows us to rewrite, with $b_0 := 0$ and $b_j := a_{j-1}$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$,
$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^{i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}b_ix^i.$$
Then $f$ has constant term $0$, so $f \in I$. Thus we have that $\langle x \rangle \subseteq I$ and hence $I = \langle x \rangle.$

For the ideal part note that by definition 
$$\langle x \rangle = \lbrace xp(x) \; | \; p(x) \in R[x] \rbrace.$$
We need to show that if $f \in \langle x \rangle$ and if $p \in R[x]$, then $pf \in \langle x \rangle$; the case for $fp \in \langle x \rangle$ will follow analogously. Write
$$ f(x) = xg(x)$$
for some $g \in R[x]$. Then
$$ pf = p(x)f(x) = p(x)xg(x) = xp(x)g(x).$$
Since $R[x]$ is a ring, $p(x)g(x)$ is a polynomial in $R[x]$; more concretely
$$ p(x)g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{m}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ib_jx^{i+j} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}c_kx^k = h(x).$$
Consequently 
$$p(x)f(x) = p(x)xg(x) = xp(x)g(x) = xh(x)$$
and hence $p(x)f(x) \in I$ for any $p(x) \in R[x]$ and $f(x) \in I$. This gives that $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$.